# How to add a custom Constraint on FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are building a Brazilian Profile on FHIR. One of our Identifier's Type is called CPF. It's similar to the US Social Security Number.

There is an algorithm to validade CPF in Brazil. Here is a sample in Javascript: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o+cpf+javascript

It's possible to write this kind of validation on FhirPath? If not, how do I define this constraint on my profile?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not pretty...

Here's a discussion thread that talks about doing modulo checks using FHIRPath: https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179266-fhirpath/topic/.E2.9C.94.20running.20modulo.20check